# How do I create an RSA public\private key pair in Windows?

Tags: windows, cryptography, rsa

How do I create RSA public\private key pair file in Windows?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can use [PuTTYgen](http://www.chiark.greenend.org.uk/~sgtatham/putty/download.html) to make a key pair.

Comment: is `puttygen` helpful even if I won't be using the key-pair for `ssh`?

Answer (score 2):

John T + or if using something like msys/cygwin you can use openssh's ssh-keygen. I usually do ssh-keygen -t rsa -b 4096

Answer (score 1):

[gpg4win](http://www.gpg4win.org/) is a windows port of gpg.